# How to use a for loop to compute correlations with mixed column types

Tags: r

I have a data frame with mixed `character`, `integer`, and `numeric` column types.

I have a specific column that I want to compute correlations for in relation to all the other variables, one at a time.

```
COLUMN NAMES    CORRELATION WITH COL X
variable 1      0.34
variable 2      0.67
variable 5      0.98
```

As you might imagine, columns 3 and 4 might be `character` type and therefore no correlations can be run in relation to them.

I attempted the following code.

```
mylist <-c()
for (column in data.frame){
  if (class(column) == "integer" | "numeric"){

    # stores correlation as a variable
    x <- cor(dataframe$columnx, column, method = "pearson")

    # should add both column name and x as a pair to the list
    mylist <- c(mylist,(list(name(column),x)))

  }
}
```

Am I construct the list properly? Or can you not operate on dataframes with a for loop in  this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it if you wanted to keep it a for loop

```
mylist <-c()  
for(i in colnames(dataframe))
{
  if (class(dataframe[,which(colnames(dataframe) == i)])  == "integer" | class(dataframe[,which(colnames(dataframe) == i)])  == "numeric")
{
x <- cor(dataframe$columnx, dataframe[,which(colnames(dataframe) == i)], method = "pearson")
mylist <- c(mylist, (paste(i,x,sep=" ")))

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `keep(is.numeric)` from purrr package to retain only numeric, then `correlate()` and `focus(_variable_)` from the corrr package to get a data frame of correlations with a particular variable. Here's an example with the iris data (which will drop the factor, `Species`), getting all correlations with Sepal.Length:

```
library(purrr)
library(corrr)

iris %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(Sepal.Length)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>        rowname Sepal.Length
#>          <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1  Sepal.Width   -0.1175698
#> 2 Petal.Length    0.8717538
#> 3  Petal.Width    0.8179411
```